# Why is framed ignoring the caption?

Tags: wrapfigure, framed, box

I'm trying to get a right justified image that is all bounded by a box. The problem is that the framed box is excluding the figure caption, and only framing the image:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}

    \begin{framed}
        \caption{A test figure with its caption}\label{fig:plots}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figures/plot_placeholder.png}
    \end{framed}

\end{wrapfigure}
```

With the result:

[image]

How can I force the frame to include the caption?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}

    \begin{framed}
        \caption{A test figure with its caption}\label{fig:plots}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{framed}

\end{wrapfigure}
a aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa a
a aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa a
a aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa a
a aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa a
\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

Please edit your question to have a complete small document that shows how you have defined the commands and produces the output you show.

Comment: I was thinking the "caption" package might be relocating the caption. A simple test with '\usepackage{caption}' only improved the vertical spacing.